# Some problem when I newly downloaded dotnet and C#

Tags: c#, .net

I recently tried to start c# and when I press 'dotnet run', vscode throws this type of error:

```
/home/user/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/net6.0/HelloWorld: relocation error: /home/user/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/net6.0/HelloWorld: symbol __pthread_key_create version GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file libpthread.so.0 with link time reference
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it looks like your operating system might not have all the dependencies it needs

Comment: This same happened with me when i downloaded c to work with. That means its not a problem of dotnet or c#

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed Visual Studio-SDK and Runtime form snap?
If so, the easiest solution is to uninstall them using snap and install them using APT.

[Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu)